# Remote access to IPython console

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have installed [IPython Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Notebook), and it is running at localhost.
But how do I run it as a web page so that I can access it remotely?
For example, `http:/174.129.237.177:8888/`.

```
root@ip-10-28-197-91:/var/www# ipython notebook
2013-12-22 12:16:22.617 [NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/root/.ipython/profile_default'
2013-12-22 12:16:22.624 [NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN: http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
2013-12-22 12:16:22.723 [NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /var/www
2013-12-22 12:16:22.723 [NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
2013-12-22 12:16:22.724 [NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://127.0.0.1:8888/
2013-12-22 12:16:22.724 [NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

I need to access my notebook through A browser (Windows OS).
Security is not important in this case; I just need to test a few commands. I have tried:

```
ipython notebook --ip='*' --pylab=inline --port=7777
```

But I get "no data received" error in Google Chrome when I go to:

```
http://174.129.237.177:7777
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed this by using *[Running a public notebook server](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.1.0/interactive/public_server.html#notebook-public-server)*.

And the post *[Create an iPython HTML Notebook on Amazon's AWS Free Tier from scratch](https://gist.github.com/iamatypeofwalrus/5183133)*.

Comment: And what is the output when you use the extra flags ?

Comment: ipython needs to be started with a profile like this # ipython notebook --ip='*' --profile=nbserver --port=7777